# Prevent automatic selection of the primary TreeView node

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have multiple tabs which represent filters for a specific view. One of those tabs is a TreeView called SOTree.
There's a button to clear all filters.

If I click a node in SOTree, it highlights said node and filters the view. I can then clear all filters, which also clears the selected nodes:

```cs
this.SelectedNodes.Clear();
this.SelectedNode = null;
```

At first, it seems to clear the selected nodes just fine. However, when I change the focus to a different window/tab and back, the **first** node of the treeview will be highlighted.

This causes two issues:

- The user might think that the filter is still active, filtering for the first node
- Clicking the node doesn't actually activate the filter, since the selection does not change. The user will have to select a different node first.

How can I prevent this automatic and unwanted highlighting of the node?

Comment: Set `TabStop = false`? Set a `TabIndex` higher than other focusable controls on that TabPage?

Comment: @Jimi No, neither of these help

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558126/actually-deselect-all-nodes-in-treeview-net) and the comments below it say you can't turn off the highlight because it shows the control has focus. But scroll down for an hack solution using a panel.

Comment: Did you move the focus to something else on TabPage change? Does your TreeView have a Root node?

Comment: @ourmandave that sounds a bit dirty, I'll take a look at it though.

Comment: @Jimi Yeah, but that'll not "deselect" the node. It does not have a root node, but I am currently experimenting with adding a dummy node

Comment: Maybe you just need to handle the `GotFocus` event (or override `OnGotFocus` in case of subclassing), check `if (filter == null) SelectedNode = null;`

Comment: @JQSOFT I tried overriding OnGotFocus, but it doesn't change the behavior. Even when unfocused, the item is still highlighted (which is barely visible, but the effects won't change). Using a dummy node didn't work either, can't hide nodes and if I create, select and remove a node it turns back to selecting the primary node.

Comment: Then maybe override the `OnDrawNode` and draw the nodes according to the current inputs. [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213766/treeview-node-highlight-colour-in-c-sharp/9993165) a simple snippet.

Comment: @JQSOFT Where can I prevent selection of the node there? The OnDrawNode method doesn't appear to handle the selection, or else I am missing it.

Comment: It will be helpful if you could paste your custom `TreeView` to understand the logic so you'd get more specific comments and answers instead of more maybes.